# Python DocX file reading - need to identify and distinguish text, tables and images

Tags: python, python-docx

I have some random docx file. It can contain plain text, images or tables. I need to go through document and identify what paragraph contains what. If it is a text, then print it, if it is image, then print IMAGE, if it is table, print its content. I can do it for text, it is easy, but indentifying pics somehow doesn't work and regarding tables i just can determine that there is one, but can't print its content.
Can anyone help please?

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document('SomeDoc.docx')
pars = doc.paragraphs
for p in pars:
    print(p.text)
...????
```

I tried XML dump and that is a way but i would like to solve it with docx module. Same with doc2txt module, works for text and tables, but not for images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `._element` attribute of the paragraph and check if it contains the XML tag for an image or table. Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to do this:

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement

def identify_content(paragraph):
    if isinstance(paragraph._element, OxmlElement) and paragraph._element.xml.startswith('<w:pict'):
        print('IMAGE')
    elif isinstance(paragraph._element, OxmlElement) and paragraph._element.xml.startswith('<w:tbl'):
        table = paragraph._element._element
        for row in table.findall('.//w:tr'):
            for cell in row.findall('.//w:t'):
                print(cell.text)
    else:
        print(paragraph.text)

doc = Document('SomeDoc.docx')
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    identify_content(paragraph)
```

The `identify_content()` function takes a paragraph object as input and checks if it contains an image or a table. If it contains an image, it prints 'IMAGE'. If it contains a table, it extracts the text from each cell of the table and prints it. Otherwise, it prints the text of the paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your code unfortunately doesn't work.  Errors are here: if isinstance(paragraph._element, OxmlElement) and paragraph._element.xml.startswith('<w:pict'):
        print('IMAGE')
    elif isinstance(paragraph._element, OxmlElement) and paragraph._element.xml.startswith('<w:tbl'):
        table = paragraph._element._element

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. This code goes through document and assesses every paragraph:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('Honzo.docx')
picCount = 0
tabCount = 0
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if picCount < len(document.inline_shapes):
        print('\033[1mPicture \033[0m')
        picCount += 1
    elif paragraph.text:
        print(paragraph.text)
    elif tabCount < len(document.tables):
        table = document.tables[tabCount]
        data = []
        keys = None
        for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
            if i == 0:
                keys = tuple(text)
                continue
            row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
            data.append(row_data)
        print('\033[1mTable:\033[0m', data)
        tabCount += 1
```